# Showing some whitespace chars, but not all, in vim?

Tags: vim, vimrc, whitespace

I'm using the `set list` and `set listchars` options in vim. I'd like to customize `set listchars` to display trailing spaces, etc., but not tabs. Is it possible to specify that I don't want a particular type of whitespace displayed?

I've tried this:

```
set listchars=tab:,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:%
```

But I got a syntax error when loading my `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discovered that although this is technically not possible, one can cheat and enter special Unicode whitespace characters (not the regular space character) as the character to display for a tab. Although this still uses vim's `hl-NonText` highlighting color, it's certainly less obtrusive.

In other words, do this (or similar):

```
set listchars=tab:  ,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:%
```

The two characters after `tab:` are **not** regular space characters - they are [U+2002](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). You can enter them in vim itself with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> (in insert mode).

So far, I haven't noticed any nasty side-effects.

Comment: Why not simply use spaces? `set listchars+=tab:\ \ `

Comment: @NikitaKouevda, I didn't know you could escape spaces like that. That works too. If you state that as answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible, unfortunately. You can only `:set list` on or off, and for those elements you don't define in `'listchars'`, the defaults will be used.

I would not recommend to always operate under `:set list`, as it has some side effects (e.g. affecting soft wrapping).

If you're just concerned about highlighting trailing whitespaces, there are plugins that do this through other means. Actually, I have written the [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) for that; the page has links to alternatives.